# CUDA linking error: undefined reference to `cyl_bessel_i0f'

Tags: cuda

Why am I getting the following linker error with the example program below?

```
test_cyl_bessel_i0f.o: In function `main':
tmpxft_00007f3f_00000000-4_test_cyl_bessel_i0f.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `cyl_bessel_i0f'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm using the following commands to compile and link the code:

```
nvcc -I/usr/local/cuda/include -c test_cyl_bessel_i0f.cu
nvcc -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -o test_cyl_bessel_i0f test_cyl_bessel_i0f.o -lcudart
```

The example program is

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <math_functions.h>

int main(void)
{
    float a;
    a = cyl_bessel_i0f(0.5f);
    printf("%f\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

I am using CUDA 7.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested above, this problem is a documentation error. Although the CUDA documentation (e.g., [1]) shows cyl_bessel_i0f (and friends) defined with the `__host__` directive, host version of these functions are not available in the CUDA Math library. NVIDIA has acknowledged the problem, and I've requested that they update the CUDA documentation. I'm posting this answer for others in case they run into the same problem.

[1] http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__SINGLE.html#group__CUDA__MATH__SINGLE

Answer (score 1):

As you have now [discovered](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/899238/undefined-reference-to-cyl_bessel_i0f-/?offset=8), there are no host implementations of these CUDA math library functions (even if there are subtle hints in the documentation and header files they there might be), and this can't work.

Comment: I've submitted a bug report to NVIDIA. For reference, the subtle hint to which talonmies is referring is that the NVIDIA Math API documentation has the cyl_bessel_i0f function declared with the `__host__` and `__device__` directives.